# Get rows from current month if older is not available

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+--------------------+---------+
|    Month (date)    |  amount |
+--------------------+---------+
| 2016-10-01         | 20      |
| 2016-08-01         | 10      |
| 2016-07-01         | 17      |
+--------------------+---------+
```

I'm looking for a query (sql statement) which satisfies the following conditions:

- Give me the value of the previous month.
- If there is no value for the previous month lock back in time until one can be found.
- If there is just a value for the current month give me this value.

In the example table the row I'm looking for would be this:

```
+--------------------+---------+
| 2016-08-01         | 10      |
+--------------------+---------+
```

Has anyone a idea for a non complex select query?

Thanks in advance,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way using MAX

```
WITH tbl AS (
    SELECT TO_DATE('2016-10-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "month", 20 AS amount FROM dual
    UNION 
    SELECT TO_DATE('2016-08-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "month", 10 AS amount FROM dual    
    UNION 
    SELECT TO_DATE('2016-07-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "month", 5 AS amount FROM dual        
)
SELECT * 
  FROM tbl
 WHERE TRUNC("month", 'MONTH') = NVL((SELECT MAX(t."month") 
                                        FROM  tbl t 
                                       WHERE t."month" < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH')), 
                                     TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH'));
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of the query. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You may need the following:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (  SELECT *
            FROM test
           WHERE TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'month') >= month
        ORDER BY CASE
                    WHEN TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'month') = month
                        THEN 0 /* if current month, ordered last */
                        ELSE 1 /* previous months are ordered first */
                    END DESC,
                    month DESC /* among previous months, the greatest first */
       )
 WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Comment: This is the right approach, +1. I came up with a much more complicated solution, which I deleted after seeing yours, which is much simpler. I posted a new solution, though - starting from your idea - since I believe I simplified it in a couple of ways, which should make it more efficient. `keep (dense_rank first/last)` is a neat aggregate/analytic function that is very helpful in this type of problems. With all said, hats off for finding the simplest approach!

Comment: Although I didn't flag this answer as the solution, I like it very much. The `order by` was the thing I haven't thought of. I'm already using the `keep (dense_rank`, so I just need to modify a small part of my query. Thanks also to @mathguy for explicitly writing this down. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by (case when to_char(dte, 'YYYY-MM') = to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM') then 1 else 2 end) desc,
                                          dte desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Actually, you don't need `row_number()` for this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from t
      order by (case when to_char(dte, 'YYYY-MM') = to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM') then 1 else 2 end) desc,
               dte desc
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: This looks fine, but since the "month" column is already in date format, and apparently already truncated to the beginning of the month, the condition in the CASE statement is better written as `dte = trunc(sysdate, 'mm')`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the nicest query but it should work.

```
select amount, date from (
  select amount, date, row_number over(partition by HERE_PUT_ID order by 
    case trunc(date, 'month') when trunc(sysdate, 'month') then to_date('00010101', 'yyyymmdd') else trunc(date, 'month')  end
    desc) r)
where r = 1;
```

I guess you have some id in table so put id column instead of HERE_PUT_ID if you want query for whole table just delete: `partition by HERE_PUT_ID`

Answer (score 0):

I added more data for testing, and an "id" column (a more realistic scenario) to show how this would work. If there is no "id" in your data, simply delete any reference to it from the solution.

Notes - `month` is a reserved Oracle word, don't use it as a column name. The solution assumes the date column contains dates that are already truncated to the beginning of the month. The trick in "order by" in the `dense_rank last` is to assign a value (ANY value!) when the month is the current month; by default, the value assigned to all other months is NULL, which by default come after any non-null value in an ascending order.

You may want to test the various solutions for efficiency if execution time is important.

```
with
     inputs ( id, mth, amount ) as (
       select 1, date '2016-10-01', 20 from dual union all
       select 1, date '2016-08-01', 10 from dual union all
       select 1, date '2016-07-01', 17 from dual union all
       select 2, date '2016-10-01', 30 from dual union all
       select 2, date '2016-09-01', 25 from dual union all
       select 3, date '2016-10-01', 20 from dual union all
       select 4, date '2016-08-01', 45 from dual union all
       select 4, date '2016-06-01', 30 from dual
     )
-- end of TEST DATA - the solution (SQL query) is below this line
select id,
       max(mth) keep(dense_rank last order by
                case when mth = trunc(sysdate, 'mm') then 0 end, mth) as mth,
       max(amount) keep(dense_rank last order by
                case when mth = trunc(sysdate, 'mm') then 0 end, mth) as amount
from inputs
group by id
order by id   -- ORDER BY is optional
;


 ID MTH         AMOUNT
--- ---------- -------
  1 2016-08-01      10
  2 2016-09-01      25
  3 2016-10-01      20
  4 2016-08-01      45
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the data in the direction you want to:

```
with MyData as
(
  SELECT to_date('2016-10-01','YYYY-MM-DD') MY_DATE, 20 AMOUNT FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT to_date('2016-08-01','YYYY-MM-DD') MY_DATE, 10 AMOUNT FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT to_date('2016-07-01','YYYY-MM-DD') MY_DATE, 17 AMOUNT FROM DUAL 
),
MyResult AS (
  SELECT 
    D.*  
  FROM MyData D
  ORDER BY 
    DECODE(
      12*TO_CHAR(MY_DATE,'YYYY') + TO_CHAR(MY_DATE,'MM'),
      12*TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY') + TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM'),
      -1,
      12*TO_CHAR(MY_DATE,'YYYY') + TO_CHAR(MY_DATE,'MM')) 
  DESC
)
SELECT * FROM MyResult WHERE RowNum = 1
```